# Can PHPUnit temporarily reset system paths before a run?

Tags: php, phpunit, phantomjs, system-paths

I'm using [phpunit-spiderling](https://github.com/OpenBuildings/phpunit-spiderling) alongside PHPUnit to run browser/functional tests on PhantomJS, installed via [jonnyw/php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs), which in turn installs the `phantomjs` binary in `<project>/bin`. Since that folder is not in the system path, I need to start tests thus:

```
PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/bin ./phpunit test/browser/tests
```

This works fine, but I expect I'll need to condense it into the raw command when I set this up on hosted CI, without the environment prefix:

```
./phpunit test/browser/tests
```

I've tried a `--bootstrap` command to run a `system()` command to reset the system path, to no avail, and I can't see anything in the manual that describes how to do this via `phpunit.xml`. Unfortunately Spiderling hard-wires the Phantom command, and it is expected to be visible in the system path.

I've also tried doing this is a `setUp()` test method, but that's too late - Spiderling will already have tried, and failed, to start up PhantomJS on a random port.

(The command `./phpunit` is just a symlink to `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`, which is PHPUnit installed via Composer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to this question, it turns out that:

- hosted CI tools offer ways of achieving this outside of PHPUnit
- Travis, which I am using, offers `phantomjs` in the standard path anyway

Thus, whilst it turns out I don't need this, there seems to be two ways to achieve it. Since my approach requires the execution of the backticks, I wonder if the `env` approach might not work. However, for completeness, here is both:

- The `env` approach is an entry in the [.travis.yml file](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Variables-in-the-.travis.yml).
- You could also try a `before_script` key with a value thus:

  ```
  before_script:
    - export PATH=`pwd`/bin:$PATH
  ```

  Since the working directory should be set to the root of the project, the `pwd` plus the subdirectory should add in the new path to the system path.